# Can a main() end running before joining all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I'm writing a simple program that calculates two squared matrix multiplication.
The program should divide the work between the number of threads I predefine.

The way I do it is that each thread calculates different lines of the resulting matrix.

So the run() method each thread executes is:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int y = 0; y < numLines; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
            result[startLine + y][x] = singleIndexCalc(startLine + y, x);
}
```

This program has no synchronization (anywhere).
So my question is if I have to take care of joining the threads before ending the main() method or it does not matter as the threads will (for sure) finish running and die.

I'm asking this as I don't want to leave running threads (something that might happen when they get stuck waiting for instance), but in this example it's just not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. It can. `main` is run by just another thread, this thread, like any other, exits when it has nothing left to do.

Comment: But this won't be the right thing to do when synchronization is involved for example. As some threads might be stuck waiting and I wouldn't want the app end running and leave some running threads... right?

Comment: I don't know what you want, only you know that.

Comment: There are many easy ways to solve it, for example - use a count down latch for the amount of threads + 1, and lock em all on it on finish. when all threads are done, including the main, only then the main will continue and end.

Comment: @OrDinari why would I use this instead of join (join blocks until return)?

Comment: I dislike join, so its just a preference, but as i said, there are many ways to solve it, as long as you make sure all the threads are done before main ends you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main thread can end running before other threads end.

Look at the `setDaemon()` method of the `Thread` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)

> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.
>
> This method must be invoked before the thread is started.

The JVM will shut down after all *non-daemon* threads are finished executing.

In your case, once the main thread, and the worker threads are finished executing, the JVM will shut down, and program will end.

An interesting note: if the main thread doesn't call `join()` on any of the worker threads, it could actually end before the worker threads finish executing.